# Isolate similar file names in an array for additional processing

Tags: powershell, file, sorting

I have a small script that sorts video files by their resolution.  However some files are of the same video but in different resolutions.  Their names are the same except for 2 extra characters after one of the files names. i.e. Stream12345.ts and Stream12345_2.ts.  I want to find these similar files in the array and process them into a seperate folder, "Duplicate - " + $METAMediaFrameHieght, but can't work out where in the script or the logic to do it.

```
$VideoExtensions = ('.mp4','.ts')
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot | Where-Object {$_.Extension -in $VideoExtensions}
FOREACH ($file in $Files)
{
  $Shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
  $Folder = Split-Path $file.FullName
  $ShellFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($Folder)
  $ShellFile = $ShellFolder.ParseName($file)

  $METAMediaFrameHieght = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile, 314)

  New-Item $PSScriptRoot\$METAMediaFrameHieght -Type Directory -Force | Out-Null
  Move-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Destination $PSScriptRoot\$METAMediaFrameHieght
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex filter to capture all files that have `_number.ts` or `_number.mp4`.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot | Where-Object {$_.Extension -in $VideoExtensions}

$FilesToMove = $Files | ? {$_.Name -match "(_\d*.(ts|mp4)$)" }

if ($FilesToMove){
    $FilesToMove | Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination destPath 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly there except for parsing out the files with `_number` at the end of the BaseName and there is no clean-up afterwards to clear the COM objects from memory.

This should do what you want:

```
$Shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$VideoExtensions = ('.mp4','.ts')
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot | 
    Where-Object {$_.Extension -in $VideoExtensions -and $_.BaseName -match '_\d+$'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $ShellFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($_.DirectoryName)
        $ShellFile   = $ShellFolder.ParseName($_.Name)
        $frameHeight = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile, 314)
        $destination = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath $frameHeight
        # test if the destination path exists and if not, create it
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force
        }
        # move the file
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destination -WhatIf
}

# Clean up COM objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ShellFile)   | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ShellFolder) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell)       | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

When you are satisfied with the information displayed in the console, you can remove the `-WhatIf` switch to actually move the files.